# How to create a Gunicorn custom application with Click commands?

Tags: python, gunicorn, python-click

I am trying to build a custom application using `gunicorn` server with `flask` framework utilizing `click` commands.
I used the class `App` to create an application that has the command `say_hello` which outputs `Hello` to the terminal:

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication

class App(BaseApplication):
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = Flask(__name__)
        super(App, self).__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = dict([(key, value) for key, value in self.options.items()
                       if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None])
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application

    @click.command()
    def say_hello(self):
        print('Hello')

options = {
    'bind': '%s:%s' % ('127.0.0.1', '5000'),
    'workers': 2
}

app = App(options)
```

When I try to run this app using the command `gunicorn test:app`, I get this error:

```
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302113] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302113] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (302113)
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302113] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302114] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 302114
Application object must be callable.
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302114] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 302114)
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302113] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2022-12-30 14:39:20 -0500] [302113] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

If I change `app = App(options)` to `app = App(options).application`, the application starts with one worker but the workers are set to 2 in the source code.

How to create a custom application that has Click commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `app.run()` to run the Gunicorn custom application.

Make running the Gunicorn server another Click (group) command, instead of making the Click command an instance method of the Gunicorn custom application:

```py
@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


@cli.command()
def runserver():
    app.run()


@cli.command()
def say_hello():
    print('Hello')


cli()
```

Run command for Gunicorn custom application:

```bash
python test.py runserver
```

Run command for CLI program:

```bash
python test.py say-hello
```

References:

- https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html
- https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/